# 'man' converts hyphens to minus-hyphens

Tags: unicode, encoding, pager

I use [nvimpager](https://github.com/lucc/nvimpager) as my pager.

When I run for example `man gpg`, and I search for "-e" by typing "/-e", it finds nothing.

This is because my keyboard types "-", which is U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, while the man page uses "‐", which is U+2010 HYPHEN.

How can I convert the HYPHEN of the manpage into the HYPHEN-MINUS that my keyboard types?

Comment: I have the same issue although my pager is less. I also checked the raw files:
/usr/share/man/man1/*.1.gz and they have the hyphen-minus. So there is a conversion taking place somewhere before the pager.

man gpg | grep --word-regexp --regexp=-e
gives no result

</usr/share/man/man1/gpg.1.gz gunzip | grep --word-regexp --regexp=-e
gives: .B  -e

Answer (score 0):

OK, I also got a workaround for you, which you can use to create a bash alias as well if you want:

```
man --encoding=US-ASCII gpg
```